# ways to integrate apk in our existing android project

Tags: android, jar, apk

I have only .apk file(Barcode Scanner app) with me not the source code of that and wants to add it in my working android project so can anyone assist me the way to achieve that..?? I would be very obliged.

Comment: Whats your point of including it?

Comment: The barcode API is already in the Android SDK...

Comment: Trying to include the APK with your app is definitely WRONG. Not only that, but you won't be able to install it anyway (unless the user disables the app source security settings)

Comment: wow..this is taking open source application development to the extreme. I would rather just use the barcode API that is pre-existent and build on it. Nonetheless, good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the barcode scanner with your application without actually including the source inside of your app. Have a look at [scanning via intents](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent), this should accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks alot Bobbake4 for ur precious response as it really helped me to achieve and execute my application completly...

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the same issue. I have concluded that its not possible to include an apk file in an excisting project. But there is another possibility, using zxing open source lib. Here is a good tutorial for integrating a native barcode scanner:

**http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/**